# Minecraft end.ogg file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my Minecraft folder, I went into my Minecraft mob sounds folder named "enderdragon". I just assumed that that is where all the enderdragon sound effects are kept, and I was partially right. I found a file called "end.ogg". I clicked, it, and it played an eight second song about a person being a milkman. Is that some sort of easter egg in Minecraft? Oh and, I am using 1.8[image]

Comment: Interesting....

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and comments, but I'm 100% sure no one trolled me, since no one other than me has access to my computer. Also, does anyone else have this 8 second milk-man song? I find it odd that there is NO INFORMATION on it whatsoever. 

I did some more digging around, and I found that I have two files named end.ogg One is the regular death sound of the enderdragon, while the other end.ogg file is the milk-man song. Can anyone else try searching for the milk-man song on their computer? I'd like to see if anyone else has it.

Comment: I spent about 2 hours of my life wasting my time. I now realize that the end.ogg file was actually a part of a texture pack or mod that I downloaded a long time ago. Thanks to everyone who helped though.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that someone trolled you with that sound file (does anyone other than you have access to your computer?). end.ogg is the enderdragon death sound played upon defeat of the boss (while it is blowing up/glowing/dropping XP and the end portal).

The original file is 257,102 bytes or about 251 KB. Seeing as your copy of the file is 238 KB it is clear the file you have is not the original.

Besides all this, as I was looking around through my files I found out that Minecraft no longer stores its sound files in the resources folder. Sounds are now indexed by the version of the game you are currently playing, so for example, if you play Minecraft 1.8.x the index file will be .minecraft\assets\indexes\1.8.json.

To find an individual sound file in the index first find its original directory name (for end.ogg this would be minecraft/sounds/mob/enderdragon/end.ogg) in the index, then keep track of the first 4-6 digits in the "hash" value for the sound file.

```
"minecraft/sounds/mob/enderdragon/end.ogg": {
  "hash": "**53cc18**90ebea833d3964c7dd1c90676650e34404",
  "size": 257102
},**strong text**
```

Finding the location of the new file only depends on the first 2 digits but the file itself contains the entire hash (although you can usually identify a single file by the first 4-6 digits in the hash).

Go to .minecraft\assets\objects\ and find the file with the same name as the hash code you found in the index. File extensions (such as .ogg) were stripped, but if you copy the file out of that folder to somewhere that won't be deleted next time you start the game (such as your desktop) you can re-add the extension and use the file as you normally would.

Comment: I thought credits.ogg was the track that played after defeating the enderdragon?

Comment: credits.ogg is the track that is played when you jump into the end portal and the credits/poem/thingy plays. end.ogg is the screeching/howling/miserably dying sound the enderdragon makes when you kill it. Anyways, the file you are looking at now has lost relevance to the actual gameplay (will update answer). Sounds are now indexed by a hash value as seen in .minecraft\assets\indexes\versionnamehere.json. Still, even in the relocated version of end.ogg, the file size is 251 KB